# How to find the sum $\frac{1}{1^4+1^2+1}+\frac{2}{2^4+2^2+1}+..+\frac{2015}{2015^4+2015^2+1}$?

Tags: summation

How to find the sum $\frac{1}{1^4+1^2+1}+\frac{2}{2^4+2^2+1}+..+\frac{2015}{2015^4+2015^2+1}$ ?

I'm not being able to approach the problem.Hints please!

Comment: Well, you can cancel $n$ from the top and bottom, to get $\frac1{n^3+n+1}$.

Comment: I think you'll need the digamma function (as well as the roots of $n^3+n+1$), if you want the general answer. Specifically for 2015, the answer is 0.49472.

Comment: I suspect there is a typo and the denominator is $n^4 + n^2 + 1$ instead.

Comment: @achillehui oh no!!!!sorry!!

Comment: Hint: $\frac{n}{n^4+n^2+1} = \frac{n}{(n^2+1)^2-n^2}
= \frac12\left(\frac{1}{n^2-n+1} -  \frac{1}{n^2+n+1}\right)$ and...

Comment: I sincerely apologize for the typographical error..I typed in a hurry..thanks achille hui for pointing it out :)

Comment: @achillehui oh yes..done telescopic series :-D good idea!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notice that:
$$ \frac{n}{n^4+n^2+1}=\frac{n}{(n^2+n+1)(n^2-n+1)} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n^2-n+1}-\frac{1}{n^2+n+1}\right)$$
and that:
$$ \frac{1}{(n+1)^2-(n+1)+1}=\frac{1}{n^2+n+1}.$$

Together they give:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{n=1}^{2015}\frac{n}{n^4+n^2+1}&=&\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{2015}\left(\frac{1}{n^2-n+1}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2-(n+1)+1}\right)\\&=&\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2016^2-2016+1}\right)=\color{blue}{\frac{2031120}{4062241}}.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Answer (score 0):

You might want to prove by induction that the sum

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i}{i^4+i^2+1} = \frac{\frac{1}{2} n(n+1)}{n^2+n+1}$$